# Append string to mutablestring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablestring

```
NSString *str= @"surname";
NSMutableString *consonants = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *vowels = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i < [str length]; i++){
    if ([str characterAtIndex:i] != 'a' && [str characterAtIndex:i] != 'e' && [str characterAtIndex:i] != 'i' && [str characterAtIndex:i] != 'o' && [str characterAtIndex:i] != 'u') {
            [consonants appendFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]];
        }
        else{
            [vowels appendFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }


 if([consonants length] < 3){
      [consonants appendFormat:@"%@", [vocali characterAtIndex:1]];
 }
```

**My problem is the follow:**
if there are less of 3 consonant, I must append n vowels to consonants string.

**Examples:**
str = "mario";
consonants = "mra"; // 2 consonants and 1 vowels

str = leo;
consonants = "leo"; // 1 consonant and 2 vowels

Thk.

Comment: I've read and read your question, and I just don't understand what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the input string will be greater or equal to 3 you can just use a while loop:

```
int i = 0;
while([consonant length]<3){
   [consonant appendFormat:@"%c",[vocali characterAtIndex:i]];
   i++
}
```

Comment: If that answers the question check the checkmark on the left side.